# Testlink integration with redmine (interface:rest) is not working

Tags: php, redmine, testlink, redmine-api

We have Redmine & Testlink hosted on 2 different servers on Amazon Cloud.
I used below methods / workarounds to establish a connection between these two, however I am getting "**Something is preventing to connect to bug tracking system, it will create performance issue...**" on Execute Test page of testlink.

- Made below configuration in Issue Tracker Management under

Redmine(interface:rest)

```
<issuetracker>
    <apikey>3fe68920f3cf</apikey>
    <uribase>https://odessa.sharred.net</uribase>
    <uriview>https://odessa.sharred.net/redmine/CM/issues/</uriview> <!-- for Redmine 1.x add show/ --> 
    <projectidentifier>Common</projectidentifier>
    </issuetracker>
```

- Enabled API from redmine.
- Made settings in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\redmine-php-api\lib\redmine-rest-api.php for curl_setopt() to allow to use HTTPS.
- Tried giving Redmine Base URL using IP ADDRESS instead of Host name.
- Do not see any relevant logs in testlink's events section.
- Added entry of redmine  in config.inc.php with $g_interface_bugs='REDMINE';
- Also observed that URL given in URIBASE is opening in web browser with parameter passed as key i.e. `https://odessa.sharred.net?key=3fe68920f3cf`
  is accessible from testlink server.

Any insight / solution on this issue will be great help.

Comment: Have you checked redmine's logs?

Answer (score 0):

```
Your configuration should look something like this.



    <issuetracker>
    <apikey>3fe68920f3cf</apikey>
    <uribase>https://ServerIP/redmine</uribase>
    <uriview>https://ServerIP/redmine/issues/</uriview>
    <projectidentifier>CM</projectidentifier>
    </issuetracker>




I also had trouble and just got it working now.
If you still have issue goto http://TLServerIP/testlink/lib/events/eventviewer.php and check the error
Similarly you can go to //redmineinstalldir/apps/redmine/htdocs/log/production.log to see what error you are getting after you click test connection on testlink
```